# SQL Query Error - Violation of Primary Key constraint

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to take my information from a Data Extension which contains new customer emails and put them in another Data Extension which severs as our companies master list.

I am able to populate the Temp Id on the New_Customer_Signup however when I try to update the RMWL_Master_Email_List (the activity that this query that drops the data into I get this error message, "Query failed during execution.

> Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'RMWL Master Email List'. The duplicate key value is (Temp Id)

I checked to make sure that the Temp Id didn't already exist in our Master List and it does not. Any ideas?

```
select 
'Temp ID' as 'Subscriber Key',
'Email Address' as 'Email',
'First Name' as 'First Name',
'Last Name' as 'Last Name',
'Date Added' as 'Date Added'
from New_Customer_Signup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is inserting literal strings into each column.

Also no need to alias columns if you're not changing the name.

Give this a try:

```
select 
  [Temp ID] as 'Subscriber Key'
, [Email Address] as 'Email'
, [First Name]
. [Last Name]
, [Date Added]
from New_Customer_Signup
```

Comment: Thank you so much Adam this worked perfectly. I appreciate your time!